# Issue with scrollify and nav-button

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-scrollify

This is my webpage.

HTML:
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="./style.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="./jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.scrollify({
            section : ".scroll-div",
            sectionName : "section-name",
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            scrollSpeed: 700,
            offset : 0,
            scrollbars: false,
            standardScrollElements: "",
            setHeights: true,
            overflowScroll: true,
            updateHash: true,
            touchScroll:true,
            before:function() {},
            after:function() {},
            afterResize:function() {},
            afterRender:function() {}
            });
        });
        
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="section section-1 scroll-div" id="Home">

        <div class="nav-bar" >
            <img src="./Assets/Images/Logo/logo-ww.png" alt="">
            <input class="menu-icon" type="checkbox" id="menu-icon" name="menu-icon"/>
            <label for="menu-icon"></label>
            <nav class="nav">       
                <ul class="pt-5"> 
                    <li><label for="menu-icon" onclick="$.scrollify.move('#1');">Home</label></li>
                    <li><label for="menu-icon" onclick="$.scrollify.move('#2');">La nostra storia</label></li>
                    <li><label for="menu-icon" onclick="$.scrollify.move('#3');">I nostri servizi</label></li>
                    <li><label for="menu-icon" onclick="$.scrollify.move('#4');">Prenota online</label></li>
                    <li><label for="menu-icon" onclick="$.scrollify.move('#5');">Contattaci</label></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <img src="./Assets/Images/wall.png" alt="">     
    </div>
    <div class="section section-2 scroll-div" data-div-name="second">
        <!-- Contenuto della sezione 2 -->
    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.section {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.section-2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.section img {
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}


/*------------Nav-Bar----------*/

.nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    height: 16vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 500;
    top: 0;
}

.nav-bar img {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    margin-left: -5vh;
}


/*------------Nav-Bar----------*/


/*------------Nav-Button----------*/

[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.menu-icon:checked+label,
.menu-icon:not(:checked)+label {
    position: fixed;
    top: 63px;
    right: 75px;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}

.menu-icon:checked+label:before,
.menu-icon:not(:checked)+label:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 2px solid #ececee;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ececee;
    transition: border-width 100ms 1500ms ease, top 100ms 1600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), height 100ms 1600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), background-color 200ms ease, transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.menu-icon:checked+label:after,
.menu-icon:not(:checked)+label:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 10px;
    right: 4px;
    background-color: #ececee;
    margin-top: -1px;
    transition: width 100ms 1750ms ease, right 100ms 1750ms ease, margin-top 100ms ease, transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.menu-icon:checked+label:before {
    top: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ececee;
    border-width: 0;
    transition: border-width 100ms 340ms ease, top 100ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), height 100ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), background-color 200ms 500ms ease, transform 200ms 1700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.menu-icon:checked+label:after {
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: width 100ms ease, right 100ms ease, margin-top 100ms 500ms ease, transform 200ms 1700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 33px;
    right: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    animation: border-transform 7s linear infinite;
    transition: top 350ms 1100ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), right 350ms 1100ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 250ms 1100ms ease, width 650ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), height 650ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

@keyframes border-transform {
    0%,
    100% {
        border-radius: 63% 37% 54% 46% / 55% 48% 52% 45%;
    }
    14% {
        border-radius: 40% 60% 54% 46% / 49% 60% 40% 51%;
    }
    28% {
        border-radius: 54% 46% 38% 62% / 49% 70% 30% 51%;
    }
    42% {
        border-radius: 61% 39% 55% 45% / 61% 38% 62% 39%;
    }
    56% {
        border-radius: 61% 39% 67% 33% / 70% 50% 50% 30%;
    }
    70% {
        border-radius: 50% 50% 34% 66% / 56% 68% 32% 44%;
    }
    84% {
        border-radius: 46% 54% 50% 50% / 35% 61% 39% 65%;
    }
}

.menu-icon:checked~.nav {
    animation-play-state: paused;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    transition: top 350ms 700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), right 350ms 700ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 250ms 700ms ease, width 750ms 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), height 750ms 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 6;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    list-style: none;
}

.nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(30px);
    transition: all 250ms linear;
}

.nav ul li:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.nav ul li:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 150ms;
}

.nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.nav ul li:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}

.nav ul li:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}

.nav ul li label {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 9vh;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #ececee;
    transition: all 250ms linear;
}

.nav ul li label:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffeba7;
}

.nav ul li label:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    content: '';
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: -1vh;
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #353746;
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: width 250ms linear;
}

.nav ul li label:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-icon:checked~.nav ul li {
    pointer-events: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: opacity 350ms ease, transform 250ms ease;
}

.menu-icon:checked~.nav ul li:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 1400ms;
}

.menu-icon:checked~.nav ul li:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 1480ms;
}

.menu-icon:checked~.nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 1560ms;
}

.menu-icon:checked~.nav ul li:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 1640ms;
}

.menu-icon:checked~.nav ul li:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 1640ms;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .menu-icon:checked+label,
    .menu-icon:not(:checked)+label {
        right: 55px;
    }
    .logo {
        left: 30px;
    }
    .nav {
        right: 30px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 9vw;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 2px transparent;
        text-stroke: 2px transparent;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffeba7;
        text-fill-color: #ffeba7;
        color: #ffeba7;
    }
    .nav ul li label {
        font-size: 5vh;
    }
}


/*------------Nav-Button----------*/
```

The script.js is empty so it's useless to put it here.

Hi all, I have a problem with my "site" that I'm developing, when I click the nav-bar button it opens correctly and when I click the lable it goes to the right section, but when I close the lable selection screen, when I want reopening it the site automatically jumps to the first section instantly. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this "bug"? Thanks everyone for the assistance.

Comment: Ps: the problem occurs only on chrome, it works perfectly on safari

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).